# Is there any way to print template class object

Tags: c++, oop, runtime, template-classes

I am trying to create template class for storing different values, for instance, I have a list, which can hold value of any type.

```
template<class T>
class LinkedNode
{
private:
    LinkedNode* next;
    LinkedNode* previous;
    T data;
```

Is there any way to print value of data. Or in some way specify that T type should have print method. I a little bit confused, because I came from Java. In Java every class is inherited from Object that has `toString()` method. How can I print value of T type that will be only resolved in runtime.
What is solution in C++ ? Or I have to use some class as base class (virtual) that will have desired method.
I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your `<<` operator

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, LinkedNode const& node)
{
    return os << node.data;
}
```

This would require that whatever type `T` is has `<<` defined.

Comment: Note that this needs to be a template.

Comment: Also you either need a public getter for `data` if the member is private, or this operator needs to be declared a `friend` of your class.